# Get Battery consumed for a single network call

Tags: android, performance, android-networking

I want to check how much battery is consumed for a particular network call in my app,Is it actually possible to do so. If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get battery info from the following method:

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
    if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
        return 50.0f;
    }

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f;  }
```

So you can call this method before and after of the network call. And find the difference.